# How to compile eigen with VS2019, /std:c++latest and /Zc:__cplusplus

Tags: visual-studio-2019, eigen, c++20

I'm trying to compile eigen 3.3.9 fron the github mirror with VS2019, `/std:c++latest` and `/Zc:__cplusplus`

What i get is a

```
eigen\Eigen\src\Core\util\Meta.h(320,25): error C2039: 'result_of': is not a member of 'std'
```

because `EIGEN_HAS_STD_RESULT_OF` is defined. This get's determined [here](https://github.com/eigenteam/eigen-git-mirror/blob/branches/3.3/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h#L391):

```
#ifndef EIGEN_HAS_STD_RESULT_OF
#if EIGEN_MAX_CPP_VER>=11 && ((__has_feature(cxx_lambdas) || (defined(__cplusplus) && __cplusplus >= 201103L)))
#define EIGEN_HAS_STD_RESULT_OF 1
#else
#define EIGEN_HAS_STD_RESULT_OF 0
#endif
#endif
```

From what i [can read](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of), `std::result_of` is removed in C++20 which is not reflected in the check above.

Am i doing something wrong? Is there an easy way to compile eigen with VS, C++20 and a `__cplusplus` define which [reflects the actual standard version](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-now-correctly-reports-__cplusplus) without having to [manually set all the defines](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPreprocessorDirectives.html) myself or patching Macros.h?

Comment: The `#if` check appears to have been updated in the current eigen sources [here](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/master/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h#L667).

Comment: @dxiv Hopefully they port it back to the stable 3.3.x soon :)